# Fragment goes out of the screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I just added fragments to the  Main_Activity and now I am swapping them with the drawer layout, 
The problem here is that the fragment is not contained inside inside the screen  as shown in the figure, 
I will provide the code if anyone needs it.

Briefly, I have added a linear layout in which the fragment is swapped

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Here is the code Requested:

HEER"activity_main.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="7dp">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"

        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

HERE IS THE MAIN ACTIVITY CLASS:

```
    package com.rateker.ratekerand.ratekerandroid;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TITLES[] = {"Home", "Events", "Mail", "Shop", "Travel", "Home2", "Events2", "Mail2", "Shop2", "Travel2", "Shop3", "Travel3"};
    int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult,
            R.drawable.abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult,
            R.drawable.abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult,
            R.drawable.abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult,
            R.drawable.abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult,
            R.drawable.abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult,
            R.drawable.abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult,
            R.drawable.abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult,
            R.drawable.abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult,
            R.drawable.abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult,
            R.drawable.abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult,
            R.drawable.abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult};

    //Similarly we Create a String Resource for the name and email in the header view
    //And we also create a int resource for profile picture in the header view

    String NAME = "Akash Bangad";
    String EMAIL = "akash.bangad@android4devs.com";
    int PROFILE = R.drawable.lighthouse;

    private Toolbar toolbar;                              // Declaring the Toolbar Object

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                           // Declaring RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;                        // Declaring Adapter For Recycler View
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;            // Declaring Layout Manager as a linear layout manager
    DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring DrawerLayout

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);                   // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES, ICONS, NAME, EMAIL, PROFILE);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
        // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
        // and header view profile picture
        final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

        });


        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
//                child.getVerticalScrollbarPosition()
                if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                    Drawer.closeDrawers();
                    System.out.println("@@@@@ !!!!!");
                    int position = mRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
                    Fragment fragment = null;
                    switch (position) {
                        case 1:
                            fragment = new FragmentHome();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            fragment = new FragmentEvents();
                            break;
                        default:
                            fragment = new FragmentOthers();
                            break;
                    }


                    openFragment(fragment);
                    return true;

                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }
        });
//                setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
//                                    int position, long id) {
//                openActivity(position);
//            }
//        });
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager


        Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, Drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
                // open I am not going to put anything here)
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
            }


        }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
        Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();


    }

    private void openFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments

//        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
//        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//                .replace(R.id.content_frame, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
//                .commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

HERE IS ONE OF THE FRAGMENTS CLASS:

```
package com.rateker.ratekerand.ratekerandroid;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;


/**
 * A simple {@link android.app.Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenthome, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

HERE IS THE FRAGMENT'S XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=" HOME 1  HOME 2 HOME 3 HOME 4 HOME 5 HOME 6 HOME 7 HOME 8 HOME 9 HOME 11 HOME 12 HOME 13 HOME 14 HOME 15 HOME 16 HOME 17 HOME 18 HOME 19"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml & activity's java code so that I can help

Comment: sorry i just found out that there was a problem with the window height and width in my emulator. I adjusted it and it works fine, thanks for the response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - View hidden behind AppBarLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992671/android-view-hidden-behind-appbarlayout)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that i had a problem with the width and height of an emulator. The window height should be the same as the guest height, same for width.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

in API Level 8+  Use match_parent.
Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" > 

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry i just found out that there was a problem with the window height and width in my emulator. I adjusted it and it works fine, thanks for the response.