# Android - View hidden behind AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appbarlayout

I have the problem that my RecyclerView is cut off behind the AppBarLayout

[image]

Here is my XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_tool_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:color="@android:color/white"
            app:contentScrim="@color/blue_grey_900"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loadingProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        app:layout_behavior="irisrecognition.example.com.irisrecognition.adapter.ScrollAwareFABBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot to specify the `RecyclerView`'s `layout_behavior`. Add this line

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to your `RecyclerView`'s XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```